# Picking cards sequentially vs consecutively

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, card-games

We have a pack of 6 cards over the table. Cards are: {A, A}, {B, B}, {C}, {D}.

There are 3 players (**Papa**, **Pepe**, **Popo**) sat around the table. Cards are all upside down, so the players cannot see which card they are picking.

**Now we are presented with two scenarios:**

- **Case 1:** each player picks one card at a time. That is, first Papa picks a card, then Pepe, then Popo, until there are no cards over the table (i.e. cards are being picked *sequentially*).
- **Case 2:** each player picks their 2 cards directly, that is: Papa picks 2 cards, then Pepe, then Popo. (i.e. cards are being picked *consecutively*).

I am being asked if the probability that **Papa** has the two A's is the same (or not) for both cases.

My knowledge on statistics and probability is not very advanced, but I'd say that the chance for **Papa** picking the two A's will not be the same, but I don't have a convincing argument in favour. Maybe someone could point me towards the right direction in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**

For Papa to get two As, Papa needs to pick an A first out of the $6$ cards, then Pepe needs to pick not an A out of the remaining $5$ cards, then Popo needs to pick not an A out of the remaining $4$ cards, and then Papa needs to pick the other A out of the remaining $3$ cards.

**Case 2**

For Papa to get two As, he needs to pick an A first out of the $6$ cards and then he needs to pick the other A out of the remaining $5$ cards.

In both cases, we simply need to take the probabilities of each card pick happening and multiply them together, which shouldn't be too hard. Then, once you've done that for both cases, you can compare them to see if they are the same or not.

---

Now, as you found, both cases have the same probability of $\frac{1}{15}$. To understand why, let's consider the general case where the picking order could *anything*, as long as Papa picks two cards.

Instead of thinking of it like this, however, let's think of this as a string of letters including $AABBCD$ in the order that the cards are picked. For example, the string $ABCABD$ means that someone picks $A$, then $B$, then $C$, then $A$, then $B$, then $D$. However, these "someone"s could be anyone as long as two of these people are Papa.

Now, in the first case, Papa picks the first and fourth card. The probability that the first card is an A is $\frac 2 6$. Now, given that, there are now five other cards in the picking order and one A left, so the probability that the fourth card is an A is $\frac 1 5$. Thus, the probability for this case is $\frac 2 6*\frac 1 5=\frac 1 {15}$.

In the second case, Papa picks the first and second card. The probability that the first card is an A is $\frac 2 6$. Now, given that, there are now five other cards in the picking order and one A left, so the probability that the second card is an A is $\frac 1 5$. Thus, the probability for this case is $\frac 2 6*\frac 1 5=\frac 1 {15}$.

Notice that for both cases, we have exactly the same logic, just different spots Papa is picking the cards from. This is because we are thinking about this in terms of letters in a string instead of cards picked in an order, so we don't need to worry about all of the letters before or in between. Thus, as long as each person picks two cards, the probability that Papa gets two As is $\frac 1 {15}$.

Comment: Easier than what I thought @NobleMushtak, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: So I did it and gives me the same result for both cases. Is it possible to extrapolate the result for a given number of cards (each card repeating a given number of times) and a given number of people? The way cards are being picked doesn't matter? Even if the picking order/amount is irregular?

Comment: @JosePerez Yes, you should get the same number for both cases. However, the solution I gave is the easy solution. We have to think more creatively to see why this is true for the general case. I will edit my answer above to include the general solution and comment here to tell you when I am finished.

Comment: @JosePerez OK, I have edited my answer above to include the general case.

Comment: Beautiful explanation @NobleMushatk, I feel like this needs to be the answer to accept. Does your solution hold if we had something like, AAABCCDEEEEEEFFG...? That is, random repetition of cards, and a given number of players (always that mod(num of cards, num of players)=0)?

Comment: @JosePerez Actually, we can be even more general. Even if everyone does not pick the same number of cards and even if the number of players changes, as long as the number of cards Papa picks is constant, then you will get the same number of cards regardless. For example, if we have $AABBCD$ again, if Papa picks a card, then Pepe, then Popo, then Pupu, then Papa, then Pepe, you will still get a probability of $\frac 1 {15}$ because even though now, we have four people, Papa is still picking two cards.

Comment: Before, I was being too specific with making everyone choose two cards, but honestly, the only thing we need is that Papa picks two cards from $AABBCD$ for the probability to be $\frac 1 {15}$.

Comment: Alright, thank you again for your time @NobleMushtak. :)

Comment: @JosePerez Glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

The probabilities that Papa picks two A's are actually the same.

- Case 1

Probability of Papa picks A: $\frac{2}{6}$

Probability of Pepe picks cards other than A: $\frac{4}{5}$

Probability of Popo picks cards other than A: $\frac{3}{4}$

Probability of Papa picks A again: $\frac{1}{3}$

So, probability of Papa picks two A's : $\frac{2}{6}\times \frac{4}{5} \times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{15}$

- Case 2

Probability of Papa picks A: $\frac{2}{6}$

Probability of Papa picks A again: $\frac{1}{5}$

So, probability of Papa picks two A's : $\frac{2}{6}\times \frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{15}$

Comment: Easy calculations then! I thought it was going to be a bit more complex than that. Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong. It should be $\frac 2 6$, so the probability is $\frac 2 6*\frac 1 5=\frac 1 {15}$. You have the right idea, though.

Comment: @NobleMushtak my mistake. just fixed that.

Comment: @Steven You also need to fix it in Case 2.

Comment: @NobleMushtak thanks again